# setting .prop() value programatically of select control in j-Query mobile radio button (Data-Native-Menu ="true") not updated in android 4.2.1

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, jquery-selectors

What happens when selected index is updated(`$('#idSelectControl').prop('selectedIndex', self.lastSelected);`). Immediately the radio button is not getting refreshed, I need to close the select drop down when I reopen the control, it's showing the updated radio button checked with the current selected index.

Please find the code below.

HTML

```html
<div id="idSelectCustomControl" data-bind="visible : searchVisibleFlag">
  <select id="idSelectControl" class="float-left big-select" data-native-menu="true" data-corners="false" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="left" data-mini="true" data-bind="dataOptions: arrayList, optionsText : 'text', optionsValue : 'id'">
  </select>
</div>
```

JS

```js
// fired when user selects on  drop down list
$(#idSelectControl).live("change", function (event) {
    var selectedItem = $("#idSelectControl option:selected").val();
    console.log("merchant subscription" + self.merchant());       
    self.lastSelected = $('#idSelectControl').prop('selectedIndex');
    $('#idSelectControl').prop('selectedIndex', self.lastSelected);
    //$("select").selectmenu("refresh");
    var myselect = $("#idSelectControl");
    myselect[0].selectedIndex =0;
    myselect.selectmenu("refresh",true);        
    $('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
    $("select").selectmenu("close");        
    //$("#idSelectControl").val(selectedItem ).selectmenu("refresh");        
    if (selectedItem ) {
       self.item((selectedItem);
    }
    else {
        self.item("");
    }      
 });
```

I have tried below also:

```js
$("input[type='radio']").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh"); 
$('input[value='+$(this).find("HomeStatus").text()+']')
  .attr('checked',true).checkboxradio('refresh');
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, and add HTML markup.

Comment: In the event change function viz ; $(#idSelectControl).live("change", function (event) {} i am updating the selectedIndex. But what is happening selection change is not reflected in the UI (Radio buttons in Android 4.2.1). I had to click on the "Done" then again select the "select control" then UI is getting updated which option is checked.

Comment: Here is the HTML Markup.   <div id="idSelectCustomControl" data-bind="visible : searchVisibleFlag">
     <select id="idSelectControl" class="float-left big-select" data-native-menu="true" data-corners="false" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="left" data-mini="true" data-bind="dataOptions: arrayList, optionsText : 'text', optionsValue : 'id'"></select>
   </div>

Comment: does it happen only on android?

Comment: It's happening on Android 4.2.1, as the native control for this device is different for other. When you select the option you can see the selection change of radio buttons, but there you need to click on "Done" then select control "close" down.